# spark dataframe overwrite creates duplicates

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, duplicates

I have a groupby function in df as follows:

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy($"word").agg(sum($"word_num") as "cnt")

df2.write.format("csv")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t")
  .save(outputPath)
```

After save the df2, when i reload it from hdfs:

```
val pFeatureDF = spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("header","true")
  .option("delimiter","\t")
  .load(outputPath)
```

There exists duplicate key word in df2 like this:

```
word cnt
word1 10990
word1 11
word2 20980
word2 10
```

Comment: Can you please share your input file. Did you print df2.show

Comment: Might be `word1` and `word1 `.

Answer (score 2):

Since `groupBy` can't return duplicates for the aggregated keys by definition, it's probably due to spaces in the values of the column `word`.

You can remove the spaces from both sides of the value by using the function `trim`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sum, trim}

val df2 = df1.groupBy(trim($"word")).agg(sum($"word_num") as "cnt")
```